# start rails server after raspberry reboots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, raspberry-pi, raspbian, activesupport

I want my raspberry pi to start a rails server everytime it reboots.
I can start the server without any problems using "rails server".
To start the server after the raspberry pi reboots I put the command in the rc.local file.
Using this will cause an error saying that i should run bundle install due to missing gems. If I try to use bundle install it will cause another error message saying "active support '5.0.2' is missing use gem install -v'5.0.2' ".

Using the command will print the message that activesupport is sucessfully installed but if I use bundle install again the error message is still showing up.

But all the error messages are not showing up if I use rails server myself.

Comment: Please show the contents of your init file that starts the server?

Comment: "cd /workspace && rails server"    exit 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `rc.local` runs commands a root user instead of your normal user.

You should use:

`su YOUR_USER_NAME -c 'rails server'`

Comment: thank you for your reply.
i tested it using:
"sudo su "
su pi -c "cd /directory && rails s"

But still I get the error message saying that activesupport is missing

Comment: You would not use sudo as the user is already root and for the most part may not even be in the sudoers file (seeing as he can already do everything :)) So try just the su pi ... part. Another point is that often due to the reduced PATH environment at the start of  a system, you can often be well payed to use full paths to any executable being run, especially as rails might not be in root's path

Comment: I tryed it without the "sudo su" part and still got the same error message.